# Merge [google-amp] into [amp-html]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

AMP is spearheaded by Google but it's an open source project, and we already have a tag for it - [amp-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-html).

Also, [amp-img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-img) and [amp-mustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-mustache) seem way too specific.

Comment: There's one question for each of [tag:amp-img], [tag:amp-mustache], and [tag:google-amp], so I replaced them all with [tag:amp-html]. [tag:google-amp] might pop up again in the future though, it should be a synonym.

Answer (score 5):

There's one question for each of [amp-img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-img), [amp-mustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-mustache), and [google-amp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-amp), so I replaced them all with [amp-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-html).

The 3 unused tags have been [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/190066). If they reappear, you could suggest a synonym, instead of manually retagging the new questions.

Comment: [tag:amp-img] and [tag:amp-mustache] are back.