# Difference between [accelerated-mobile-page] and [amp-html] tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I faced [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19043841) suggesting to add [accelerated-mobile-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerated-mobile-page) to a previously [amp-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-html) tagged question. But reading both excerpts, I see:

For [accelerated-mobile-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerated-mobile-page):

> Similar Tags: [amp-html] and [google-amp] AMP HTML (Accelerated Mobile Pages HTML) is a project led by Google to make the mobile web faster. It is a set of HTML tags, a JavaScript library, and a cache for AMP-compliant pages.

For [amp-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-html):

> AMP HTML (Accelerated Mobile Pages HTML) is a project led by Google to make the mobile web faster. It is a set of HTML tags, a JavaScript library, and a cache for AMP-compliant pages.

They sound so similar that I preferred to skip the review. Is there a meaningful difference between them?

Somewhat related: [Merge [google-amp] into [amp-html]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342643/merge-google-amp-into-amp-html)

Comment: Closing as no longer repro'able, as the tags were merged. Let me know if you feel that it shouldn't be.

Comment: @BhargavRao merge is probably good, as we didn't get any reply for the difference between the two after more than a year from asking.