# Merge [google-amp] and [accelerated-mobile-page] into [amp-html]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

It seems that questions related to the [AMP Project](https://www.ampproject.org/) currently use 3 different tags across the website:

- **[[amp-html]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-html)** which is the most popular one and also the one [linked to from the official website](https://www.ampproject.org/support/developer/get_support)
- [[accelerated-mobile-page]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerated-mobile-page)
- [[google-amp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-amp)

Since this [already caused some confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364296/difference-between-accelerated-mobile-page-and-amp-html-tags), could we merge [accelerated-mobile-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerated-mobile-page) and [google-amp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-amp) into [amp-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amp-html)?

Comment: seems like amp-html is only one of the components of AMP pages https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/

Comment: There already is a [request to merge google-amp into amp-html](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342643/7296893). Two-for-one requests are bad form, as voting can't distinguish between the requests.

Comment: @Samuel: That page is slightly misleading: AMP JS is just the library used to render AMP HTML while AMP Cache is a mechanism for caching. Since the project name is "amphtml" on GitHub and the official website names `[amp-html]` as the tag to use, it seems that should be the "main" tag here. @Erik: Good point, makes sense. I saw that previous request, but based on the comments, the merge was done after Dan requested it, so I assume the tag simply resurfaced, which is why I decided to create a new thread.

Comment: Thinking about it, perhaps it makes sense to just make `[accelerated-mobile-page]` and `[google-amp]` synonyms for `[amp-html]` at this point? It seems the tags are used interchangeably already.